# Como transformo mysql em pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho esse *function* em mysql.

```
public function get_logst(){
        $this->connect_database(DAT5);
        $querygetl = mysql_query("select HeroName, ObjIdx from ObjLog where LogType = '5' and
        LogSubType = '2' and DataType = '2' order by LogSerial desc Limit 500");
        $this->__destruct();
        $this->connect_database(DAT3);
        while($arraygetl = mysql_fetch_row($querygetl)){
            $getmonster = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select name from s_monster where 
            type = '$arraygetl[1]'"));
            echo '<tr><td><span class="badge bg-success">'.$arraygetl[0].'</span></td>                                  
                  <td>'.$getmonster[0].'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
```

E quero transforma em pdo, tentei isso porem sem sucesso:

```
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8", "root", "");

 $teste = $pdo->prepare("SELECT bd1.*,bd2.* FROM `S_Data`.`*` as bd1 INNER JOIN `LogDB`.`ObjLog` as bd2 where bd1.`type` = bd2.`ObjIdx`");
 $teste->execute();

 $resultados = $teste->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 var_dump($resultados);
```

Estou realizando a consulta em dois bancos diferente porem no mesmo host.
A unica alteração que também quero em pdo pegar todos os campos das tabelas S_Data pois la contem todos os item tem a tabela `s_item` e `s_monster`, so que quando coloco o `*` não pega retorna um array com `0`.

Comment: Não precisa colocar crase no asterisco

Comment: A consulta que tem na forma pdo é diferente da consulta que tem na forma mysql. Não parece ser mais uma tradução. E por que você usar `S_Data.* as bd1`?

Comment: por que todas as tabelas em `S_Data` tem os mesmo formato e quero pegar todas.